# Code fails when I try to call forward function of nn.Linear

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm training a Linear Regression model (torch.nn.Linear) on simple artificial data created like this:

```
# Device Agnostic Code
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

# Parameters to be used 
weight = 0.3
bias = 0.9

# Creating a tensor containing the Input Data
start = 2
step = 2
end = 201
x_src = torch.arange(start, end, step, device=device).unsqueeze(dim=1)

# Computing y as a linear function of x_src
y = weight * x_src + bias

# Splitting data into training (80%) and testing (20%)
train_len = int(0.8 * len(x_src))
X_train, y_train = x_src[:train_len], y[:train_len]
X_test, y_test = x_src[train_len:], y[train_len:]
```

The model is defined as follows:

```
class LinearRegressionModule(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear_model = nn.Linear(in_features = 1, out_features = 1, device=device)

  def forward(self, x : torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    return self.linear_model(x)

# Creating an instance of this class
torch.manual_seed(42)
model_eins = LinearRegressionModule()
```

I try to apply call the forward function of this model like this:

```
# Calculate Fwd Function on training data
train_preds = model_eins(X_train)
```

But here, I'm running into the following issue:

[image]

What am I missing, can someone help me out?

**Update:**

Based on a suggestion about setting the datatype to float, I did so by doing adding an extra argument in the torch.arange() function:

```
x_src = torch.arange(start, end, step, device=device, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(dim=1)
```

I did the same in the class definition as well:

```
self.linear_model = nn.Linear(in_features=1, out_features=1, device=device, dtype=torch.float32)
```

This solves the issue of the datatype - **but**, there's a new issue during training. The following is the code for the training loop:

```
# Loss Function and Optimizer
loss_fn = nn.L1Loss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params = model_eins.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

### Looping through training and testing

# Initialize variables
epochs = 300

# Start the Loop
for epoch in range(epochs):
  # Enter train mode to enable gradient tracking
  model_eins.train()

  # Calculate Fwd Function on training data
  train_preds = model_eins(X_train)

  # Calculate loss on Training predictions
  train_loss = loss_fn(train_preds, y_train)

  # Reset gradients to avoid accumulation
  optimizer.zero_grad()

  # Backpropagate to calculate gradients
  train_loss.backward()

  # Use gradients to optimize parameters
  optimizer.step()
```

I tracked the train_loss value once every 10 epochs - **and it is not changing.** Basically, after 300 epochs, the model's weight and bias remain the same. I can't see any reason why, because I am initiating parameter updates via optimizer.step(). Could anyone please help me out here?

Comment: please update your question and post the trackback as text

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get you. What is a trackback? What exactly should I update in my question?

Comment: Cast your inputs to torch.float type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a `nn.Module` model, all its weights are generated with `torch.float32` data type. The tensor that you are passing to the model should also be of same data type. Here, `x_src` is of data type `int`. Convert it to `torch.float32` as follows. Other following tensors will be of the desired data type:

```py
# Creating a tensor containing the Input Data
start = 2
step = 2
end = 201
x_src = torch.arange(start, end, step, device=device).unsqueeze(dim=1).to(torch.float32)
```

Possible cause for the updated issue:

1. Toy data is used in the problem which is less in size. Moreover the X data minimum and maximum are far away, i.e., huge range. Similarly, Y data also has huge range.
2. With L1 loss and a single neuron, model struggles to converge. If you print loss for every epoch, you can observe fluctuations in loss in a repititve manner.

Solution for the updated issue:

1. Normalize inputs X to help easy and steady convergence; normalizing target Y would help greatly, but can be skipped (if Y is normalized, it should be inverted back after prediction).

```py
# create data and normalize X values
x_src = torch.arange(start, end, step, device=device).unsqueeze(dim=1).to(torch.float32)

# Computing y as a linear function of x_src
y = weight * x_src + bias

# normalize inputs
x_src = (x_src - x_src.mean()) / x_src.std()

# Splitting data into training (80%) and testing (20%)
train_len = int(0.8 * len(x_src))
X_train, y_train = x_src[:train_len], y[:train_len]
X_test, y_test = x_src[train_len:], y[train_len:]
```

2. Use L2 loss, rather than L1 loss, as it is robust for huge change in values.

```py
model_eins = LinearRegressionModule()

# Loss Function and Optimizer
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params = model_eins.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
```

When I tried, train loss went down from 800+ to 1.2 in 300 epochs and close to zero (0.12) when trained for 400 epochs.

Comment: @Gamma-ray-burst, For 500 epochs, `train_loss` is 0.022 and `validation_loss` is 0.126

Comment: Yes, this worked out! I was focusing on the datatype issue, should have realized that the data itself needed to be normalized. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first move the model to the same device as the input tensor. Change this line

```
model_eins = LinearRegressionModule()
```

to

```
model_eins = LinearRegressionModule().to(device)
```

then cast to the same data type as the weight tensor. by changing

```
train_preds = model_eins(X_train)
```

to

```
train_preds = model_eins(X_train.to(model_eins.linear_model.weight.dtype))
```

Comment: `self.linear_model = nn.Linear(in_features = 1, out_features = 1, device=device)`: model is built in the device only.

Comment: Regarding the datatype, yes I tried to set datatype to float, and that error is not popping up now (there's a new issue though). As for the device, like @rajkumar_data said, I am specifying the device while calling the respective PyTorch functions.